# Cryptic Python job ad

Tags: python

Saw this cryptic job ad in the Tube, but it appears to evaluate to `[]` which doesn't seem terribly exciting. Any ideas on how to coax a more useful result from it?

```
bytes(
    map(
        lambda x: x-1,
        filter(
            lambda y: y < sum(2**x for x in {z for z in range(7)}-{2}),
                b'~b{qq}mz!o|px'
        )
    )
)
```

https://repl.it/KkRj/0

Comment: `{z for z in range(7)}`: the guys can't write proper python...

Comment: When I run it I get "apply now". Now you can send your resume (don't tell you failed executing their ad, though)

Comment: Run it in Python 3. Perhaps that is a hint that you should not apply if you still use Python 2.

Comment: then a good question would be "why doesn't it yield something in python 2" ? oh I get it: strings vs byte values.

Comment: ah hah! Clearly they're looking for a Python developer, and embarassingly I failed the test ;)

Comment: Strangely enough I also walked past that ad this morning, and I assumed it was Erlang because I know that company does use Erlang for their backend stuff.

Comment: smarkets.com if anyone is curious, apparently an online betting shop

Answer (score 1):

in python 2, this code doesn't yield anything (empty list) because of this:

```
>>> b'a'[0] < 100
False
```

b prefix doesn't really create a `bytes` object in python 2. So you're back to comparing a string with an integer, which is always false in python 2 (not sure if the coders overlooked that or did that on purpose)

On the other hand, in python 3, comparison works properly

```
>>> b'a'[0] < 100
True
```

so the filter works and the result is `"apply now"`.

Aside: don't you *hate* this syntax `{z for z in range(7)}` when it can just be `set(range(7))` (faster & shorter) ?

Comment: I guess the whole idea was to obfuscate the code; using set comprehension like this certainly does it.

Comment: whoever writes code like this, don't apply there :)